# background Flask toyserver for testing

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, testing

I need a flask server in multithreaded mode for testing, because some test routes are themselves calling other routes on the same server (thus, in the singlethreaded `test_client` they would hang). I thought the easiest solution would be to start the server manually in a background thread - however with this setup (as shown below) the test cases fail with ConnectionError - presumably because they don't wait for the server to finish set up.

What are the best practices to set up multithreaded testing with Flask? Should I continue with this approach and add additional handling to wait for a signal from the server to be ready? Add polling with timeout on the TestCase side?

*main_test.py*

```
import sys
import unittest
from threading import Thread
from main import app

def _run_test_server():
    app.run(host='localhost', port=3000, debug=True, threaded=True)

Thread(target=_run_test_server).start()
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
tests = loader.discover('.')
runner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner()
status = runner.run(tests).wasSuccessful()
sys.exit(not status)
```

*main.py*

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost', port=3000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

*my_test_case.py*

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Baseclass for testcases
    """
    def fetch_response(self, path):
        return json.loads(
            requests.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(os.environ["ORIGIN_URI"], path)).data
        )
```

Comment: I would say that a Gunicorn (WSGI) server is a must when an application is deployed in production.

Comment: I get that, but we're not talking production here at all. The flask server is only used for testing.

Comment: "because some test routes are themselves calling other routes on the same server" is a design decision that might be worth revisiting (e.g., by pulling the test routes out as test cases)

Comment: This flask server is actually a development wrapper around serverless lambda functions that need to call other lambda functions in a cloud agnostic way. Doing it through requests on root URI was the easiest way to do this. Mocking the input routes complicates things a lot at the test definition level, so I'd really rather handle this at the test server as per the question.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve this in bash instead; with the following, `_run_test_server` function is not needed anymore. the script can be called in any directory and returns the test's exit code, thus can e.g. called as a build target.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

# set up
curr_dir=$(pwd)
script_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
cd "${script_dir}"
source .venv/bin/activate

# main tests depend on a development server being run in background.
# since we need a server in multithreaded mode, this was the easiest way to ensure
# that this server is available.
python main.py &
server_pid=$!
while ! nc -z localhost 3000; do   
  sleep 0.1
done
python main_tests.py && :
rc=$?

# clean up
kill ${server_pid}
cd "${curr_dir}"

exit $rc
```